Namespacing in Shiny with a modular application and custom JS functions
I'm building a modular Shiny application that also uses shinyjs to implement some additional javascript. The code I'm trying to implement works fine in a standalone Shiny application, and any debugging so far points to the problem being with namespacing.
From what I've read, Shiny doesn't know how to implement namespacing inside the custom JS you give it, so it has to be done manually, but I'm having trouble getting the namespacing correct as my javascript knowledge is limited, and other suggested solutions that I've tried so far haven't worked out.
Here is a minimum example of the standalone application that works. The app takes a name of a gene, queries the STRING database, and returns an embedded output of the network graph:
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- "
        shinyjs.loadStringData = function(gene) {
        console.log('loadStringData called with gene:', gene);
        getSTRING('https://string-db.org', {
            'species': '9606',
            'identifiers': gene,
            'network_flavor':'confidence'
        });
    };"

ui <- fluidPage(

      useShinyjs(),
      
      # External JS library used to build a STRINGdb network graph.
      tags$script(src="https://string-db.org/javascript/combined_embedded_network_v2.0.4.js"),
      
      extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("loadStringData")),

        mainPanel(
          textInput(inputId = "gene", label = "Gene"), value = "TP53",
          actionButton(inputId = "button", "Click"),
          tags$div(id = "stringEmbedded"),
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  onclick("button", {
    req(input$gene)
    js$loadStringData(input$gene)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

As for the modular application, the main app file loads the external JS library with the code below. Running the app in the browser shows the library being loaded.
tags$script(src="https://string-db.org/javascript/combined_embedded_network_v2.0.4.js")

Here is the relevant code from the module called 'network' from my modular Shiny application:
network_ui <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  useShinyjs()

  # From what I can tell namespacing is required inside this extendShinyjs()

  extendShinyjs(text = paste0('shinyjs.loadStringData = function(gene) {
        getSTRING("https://string-db.org", {
            "ncbiTaxonId":"9606",
            "identifiers": gene,
            "network_flavor":"confidence"})
    }'), functions = "loadStringData")
    
  grid_container(
    layout = c(
      "network_side network_main"
    ),
    row_sizes = c(
      "1fr"
    ),
    col_sizes = c(
      "320px",
      "1fr"
    ),
    gap_size = "3px",
    grid_card(
      area = "network_side",
      card_header("Settings"),
      card_body(
        textInput(ns("gene"), "Gene", "TP53"),
        actionButton(ns("button"), "Click"),
      )
    ),
    grid_card(
      area = "network_main",
      card_body(
        tags$div(id = ns("stringEmbedded")),
      )
    )
  )
}

network_server <- function(id, data) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- session$ns

    # I suspect some namespaced call to 'gene' has to also be made here when invoking loadStringData()?

    onclick("button", { 
       req(input$gene)
       js$loadStringData(input$gene)
    })

  })
}

As mentioned, when running the modular app, I can see things generally working with the module, i.e. the button works, the JS library is loaded, and there are no explicit errors in the browser console. The module just doesn't get to the part where it sends the request to STRINGdb, indicating a problem with namespacing and loadStringData() not going through.
For reference, this is the API help page from STRINGdb related to using the embedded interactive network.
https://string-db.org/help/api/#embedding-the-interactive-network.
Any help with how to properly handle namespacing with this sort of additional javascript in a modular Shiny app would be greatly appreciated.
